# How can I copy unmanaged data in C# and how fast is it?

Tags: c#

I have two unmanaged pointers in the form of `IntPtr` and want to copy data between them. How can I do this? I know the method `Marshal.Copy`, but it can only copy between unmanaged and managed.
And the second part: Is copying unmanaged data from C# slower than doing it in unmanaged C/C++ using memcpy?

---

**Edit:** I would be especially interested in a platform independet implementation.

Comment: To comment all answers given so far: There is no direct .NET (and platform independent) way to do this?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the direct C# approach (using an unsafe block and pointers).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [win32 memcpy](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msvcrt/memcpy.html) function via P-Invoke.

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll",  SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr memcpy(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, int count);
```

Apart from the (slight) overhead calling a win32 function from managed code, the actual copy performance should be the same as C/C++ code that uses the same function.

Don't forget that you can also use an unsafe block (and compiler option) and simply copy the data one byte/int/long at a time:

```
unsafe
{
    // srcPtr and destPtr are IntPtr's pointing to valid memory locations
    // size is the number of long (normally 4 bytes) to copy
    long* src = (long*)srcPtr;
    long* dest = (long*)destPtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size / sizeof(long); i++)
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }
}
```

This removes the platform dependency, but you need to be very careful with the bounds checking and pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for the unsafe code, but my C/C++ experience warns me, that one runs in a bunch of problems when trying to re-implement memcpy...

Comment: @Danvil, yes, the whole point of using .NET is to avoid code like this.  It can be useful for efficient bitmap processing etc, but should be avoided if at all possible.  However it is comforting that Microsoft still support this "shoot yourself in the foot" feature if you need it.

Comment: Calling it with this signature causes a [pInvokeStackImbalance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0htdy0k3.aspx) for me. But this was resolved by using the signature on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msvcrt/memcpy.html).

Comment: I also got the pInvokeStackImbalance, i used the kernel32.dll CopyMemory instead.

Comment: I, too, got the stack imbalance exception as mentioned above. I tried to use the pinvoke.net function signature redefinition but couldn't get it to work (basically 3rd argument: uint nBytes --> new UintPtr( nBytes)).  So I went to the kernel32.dll + CopyMemory solution below and it worked.  Important note:  my VS2008 C# code was WORKING.  Only when I dropped the code into VS2017 did it throw an exception.  Weird.

Comment: Clarification after 5-minute timeout:   my VS2008 C# code using msvcrt.dll::memcpy( UIntPtr, UIntPtr, uint) was WORKING.  It was only when I dropped the code into VS2017 did it throw an exception.

Answer (score 17):

Try [`System.Buffer.MemoryCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.memorycopy), see the bottom of the page for supported target frameworks.

I believe that the main difference between this and the other solutions that use P/Invoke is that this method avoids the P/Invoke for smaller sizes and just does the copying directly.

[Here's](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/36b8b8e26a8e2e06e000f59e19910d117bf0025b/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Buffer.cs#L142-L308) the guts of the implementation in .NET Core (latest as of 2020-09-04).

Comment: You might want to add another answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/15610236, linking to your answer here.

Answer (score 5):

Without making comments on performance, purely because I have not tested it. You can achieve the same performance as unmanaged copy by using either CopyMemory or MoveMemory from Kernel32 via interop.

Here is the declaration for CopyMemory

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr destination, IntPtr source, uint length);
```

Comment: I believe CopyMemory and RTLCopyMemory actually just use memcpy to do the actual copying.  See the winnt.h header file.

Comment: Yes you end up in ntdll memcpy.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.CopyBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.copyblock?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1#System_Runtime_CompilerServices_Unsafe_CopyBlock_System_Void__System_Void__System_UInt32_)

It seems to allow you to copy bytes from the source address (designated by a void*) to the destination address (designated by a void*).

It also overriden to support `ref byte` as the source and destination.

[edit]
Disappointingly it appears [not to be implemented in Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/Unsafe.cs)

[edit] For those who are interested in this and using Unity, you should instead look to Unity's [UnsafeUtility.MemCpy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.UnsafeUtility.MemCpy.html)

Comment: It appears not to be implemented because it cannot be implemented in pure C#. All the `Unsafe` members appear to throw an exception even in the .NET [runtime sources](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Unsafe.cs,d53e1e483d47dcc8). These are intrinsic methods with special handling. The exceptions are thrown only when invoking by reflection.

Answer (score 1):

`CopyMemory` aka `RtlCopyMemory` aka `memcpy()` will be just as fast whether called from C# or C (other than the tiny overhead of PInvoking the method itself).

Something to keep in mind, though, is that `CopyMemory` should only be used when you're sure that the source and destination ranges do not overlap.  If they do overlap, you need to use `MoveMemory` instead, which will be slower.

Here is a declaration for `CopyMeSomeMemory`, showing how many different ways you can do the same thing in .Net:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlCopyMemory")]
public static extern void CopyMeSomeMemory(IntPtr Destination, 
    IntPtr Source, uint Length);
```

For the record, I think `Buffer.BlockCopy` in .Net just wraps one of these functions, too.