# How to copy a array of unmanaged memory into the same unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, memory, copy, unmanaged

I reserved memory 10 items of 128 bytes

```
IntPtr dst = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (10 * 128);

IntPtr src1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (128);
// .... init scr1 from DLL
IntPtr src2 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (128);
// .... init scr2 from DLL
```

I need to copy the 128 bytes elements of `src1` and `src2` to `dst` at the specified offset.

**Marshal.Copy** not suitable for such purposes.
Since the `src` and `dst` in unmanaged memory area.

Answer (score 5):

The Window's API function [`memcopy`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msvcrt.memcpy) should do the trick.

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memcpy",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
    SetLastError = false)]
public static extern IntPtr memcpy(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, UIntPtr count);
```

Also, check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658394/558018

As it claims, you can use `unsafe` context to manually transfer necessary bytes.

Comment: There are no built-in method c # there for this purpose?

Comment: @Mixer If you mean the `Marshal` class, then no. Since this class is the only unmanaged worker, then no again.

Comment: I try to minimize the use of specific Windows DLL.
This impairs portability.

And How to specify the offset?
IntPtr no pointer arithmetic

Comment: That's not a Windows API function!

Comment: Where in your OP do you say it's on a Mac? That's a rather important piece of information! And if you're worried about portability, what are you doing with unmanaged code?

Comment: @MatthewWatson
There are modules that are only native code.
But they are multiplatform.

And in my code I'm trying to avoid calls that are specific to the platform.

Comment: Will you have "msvcrt.dll" installed on the Mac? It's a Microsoft C Runtime DLL. (I added the OSX tag to your OP btw)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the Windows API to do this, use [MoveMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError=false)]
static extern void MoveMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, int size);
```